# TreeView executing a javascript method when you click to expand instead of a server ping

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-controls, telerik

***Edit:  This website is the start of what i am looking for:  http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/treeview-client-basics.html but for selecting stuff, I dont see information specific to the question.  Sidenote: If you know, does the findNodeByText();  Recursively call, or is it just leaves, or what?***

Instead of the treeview expanding as per the normal server functions, i want it to execute a javascript command.  My goal is to populate the TreeView client side instead of doing it all on the server with Controls.add(child); on the server.

So with that said, how would i set it up to override the expand/collapses server ping to instead route it to my own call?

```
<telerik:RadTreeView runat="server" ID = "FieldTreeViewer" OnClientNodePopulating="nodePopulating">
   <Nodes>
       <telerik:RadTreeNode runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources: bicweb_resources, REPORT_TYPES %>" ExpandMode = "WebService" Value = "{TopNode}" ></telerik:RadTreeNode>
       <telerik:RadTreeNode runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources: bicweb_resources, UNASSIGNED_FIELDS %>" ExpandMode = "WebService" Value = "{Unassigned}"></telerik:RadTreeNode>
   </Nodes>
   <WebServiceSettings Path="webservices/FormDesigner.svc" Method="getNodesWEBSERVICE" />
</telerik:RadTreeView>
```

when clicked (carry out function) then expand accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is that to expand, you need the +, so in the control you set:

```
ExpandMode="ServerSide"
```

which gives you the expand option.  When you are doing it, to expand, you will also want to set:

```
OnClientNodeExpanded="FUNCTION"
```

This will call the function and expand.  The next this is that you will want to build the nodes.  The way I did it, was make an AJAX call to a service which would fetch me the children, then create the nodes on the clientside.  See AJAX for how to do a ajax call.  To create the nodes, was something like:

```
if (result.getChildrenFromTelTreeResult == "") {
    alert("No Children");
} else {
    var childNodes = JSON.parse(result.getChildrenFromTelTreeResult);
    var newChild;
    //alert(childNodes.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++) {
         TV.trackChanges();
         newChild = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadTreeNode();
         newChild.set_text(childNodes[i].pText);
         newChild.set_value(childNodes[i].pValue);
         //confirmed that newChild is set to ServerSide through debug and get_expandMode();
         parentNode.get_nodes().add(newChild);
         TV.commitChanges();
         var parts = childNodes[i].pValue.split(",");
         if (parts[0] != "{fe_id}") {
            newChild.set_expandMode(Telerik.Web.UI.TreeNodeExpandMode.ServerSide);
         }
    }
}
```

This will go through and create all the children.  At the very end, i have a statement that if it is a leaf, there is no expand button available.  The Default is CleintSide, so i just said essentialy.  if (!leaf){SET NODE = ServerSide}  to give it the expand options.